# Data type for yaw angle and barometer height

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am searching for a data type that can be used to publish *yaw angle*  and *barometer height* message. Like, for laser scan data we have *sensor_msgs::LaserScan scan*, what about for *yaw angle* and *barometer height*?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12468/data-type-for-yaw-angle-and-barometer-height/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any particular reason you wouldn't like to create your own message type? Create a file, say `Yaw_Alt.msg` in `msg` folder of your package and fill it with:

```
time time
float32 yaw
float32 altBaro
```

Then read [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages) for further instructions. Generally you'll need to add / uncomment `genmsg()` in your `CMakeLists.txt`. The message will be generated when you call make (rosmake) on the package. You will find generated header files under `msg_gen`.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-26**:
Thanks a lot for the guide.